# How to use R hands on table with shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I am trying to create a shiny app using rhandsontable. I am using the code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(ggplot2)


  ui = fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput ('table'))


  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$table < renderRHandsontable(mpg)}

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When i run the code i get error "rendering objects from shinyoutput not allowed"
Any idea why its happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    rHandsontableOutput('table')
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(head(mpg))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```